Forcing table on even page in memoir's subindices messes with amsmath's \numberwithin
When I use the Schweinebacke's solution to ensure that a table is placed on an even page inside memoir's subappendices environment together with amsmath's \numberwithin, then \numberwithin doesn't work anymore. That is, the table is numbered as "1.1.1" and not as "1.A.1".
How do I fix it?
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\atevenpage}[1]{%
  \afterpage{\clearpage%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \atevenpage{#1}%
    \else%
      #1%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{my_input.tex}
  \begin{table}[p]
    \caption{A table}
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
      & A & B \\
      First row & 123 & 456 \\
      Second row & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \begin{subappendices}
    \numberwithin{table}{section}
    \section{An appendix}
    \atevenpage{\input{my_input}}
  \end{subappendices}
\end{document}


Note that this is not realated to memoir as you get the same in book by adding the appendix package. I just tried the last 5 TL versions, and they all give the same output.

Isn't the problem more that because of the \atevenpages then the subappendices actually has ended before the table is inserted?

A long comment.
Try adding this to your preamble
\AddToHook{env/subappendices/begin}{\typeout{begin subapp}}
\AddToHook{env/subappendices/end}{\typeout{end subapp}}
\AddToHook{env/table/begin}{\typeout{begin table}}
\AddToHook{env/table/end}{\typeout{end table}}

Then you can see in the log that because of the delay on the table, the subappendices has already ended at the time the table runs. The \numberwithin{table}{section} is a local definition so disappears at \end{subappendices}

Is there some way to postpone subappendices ending…?

@FredrikP   It don't think so. Why do you even move it away in the first place. \aftrerpage is a rather nasty solution.

I have quite a few two-page landscape longtables. They really should start on even pages. But maybe I can find a better solution...
